# How do i force a field to be required

Tags: contributions, forms

When i add a new contribution to a contact, i would like to avoid an empty "Source" field.

I need it to be *required.

Have anyone already done this ?

thanks

Answer (score 1):

There isn't a way to do this in the user interface but you can write a small extension where you either:

- Use https://docs.civicrm.org/dev/en/latest/hooks/hook_civicrm_buildForm/ and change the field definition so that it's required.
- Use https://docs.civicrm.org/dev/en/latest/hooks/hook_civicrm_validateForm/ and set an error if the field is blank.